# Why is [bbq] better than [barbecue]? Can we please reverse the synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

So... I saw the [bbq](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bbq) tag today... and was a bit mystified to see that apparently the decision was made to make the abbreviation "bbq" the primary tag rather than the full term "barbecue"... this was discussed early on in the site creation process here: [which tag should we use [bbq] or [barbecue]](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381/which-tag-should-we-use-bbq-or-barbecue) (2010) and it seems that the consensus was to make "barbecue" the primary tag... but clearly that didn't ever happen because in 2012 it's mentioned in an answer here [Should SA create an 'official' lexicon?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1535/should-sa-create-an-official-lexicon/1538#1538)

This answer seems to show that there were certainly **more** uses of [bbq](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bbq) than there of [barbecue](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barbecue) but I don't think that makes it a *better* tag.

So, at some point it was decided to synonymize the two but I'm not sure why this was the direction it went.

Can we please reverse this and make [barbecue](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barbecue) the primary tag?

Could we please switch the order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [barbecue](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barbecue) -> [bbq](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bbq) synonym was created by a moderator August 2, 2010. But the tags weren't *merged*, so old usages of barbecue remained. So it's unsurprising that two years later when Laura posted, there were more instances of [bbq](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bbq) than [barbecue](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barbecue) - all the questions *since* the creation of the synonym were tagged [bbq](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bbq). So either she didn't realize the synonym already existed (seems most likely?), or she was just speaking hypothetically about what you might do to resolve linguistic confusion. (The actual question there was more about US/UK discrepancies.)

I'm also not sure *why* that synonym was created in that direction. It's possible it was just a total accident (I think the synonym UI was maybe less clear back then). As you say, the meta post a few days before supported [barbecue](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barbecue) as the tag to use, so I don't see any reason to preserve it.

So... I'm switching it back.